# Toggle map view won't work

Tags: carto, carto-js

I followed the Cartodb [Toggle Map View tutorial](http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/toggle_map_view.html) and I inserted the corresponding elements from my own map into the code and it's not working for some reason, all I see is a blank page. I've posted my code below, and [here is the actual map in Cartodb](http://cdb.io/1wwdXTp). All I want to do is create two buttons that allow you to toggle between the two layers of data I've created in the map.

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/themes/css/cartodb.css" />
  <script src="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/cartodb.js"></script>
  <!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v2/themes/css/cartodb.ie.css" />
  <![endif]-->
  <style>
    html, body {width:100%; height:100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
    #cartodb-map { width: 100%; height:100%; background: black;}
  </style>

  <script>
    var map;
    function init(){
      // initiate leaflet map
      map = new L.Map('cartodb-map', { 
        center: [0,0],
        zoom: 2
      })

      var layerUrl = 'http://rjharris.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/8f8fb646-6bbf-11e4-a77f-0e018d66dc29/viz.json';

var sublayers = [];

cartodb.createLayer(map, layerUrl)
  .addTo(map)
  .on('done', function(layer) {
    // change the query for the first layer
    var subLayerOptions = {
      sql: "SELECT * FROM medicaid_expansion",
      cartocss: "#medicaid_expansion {
   polygon-opacity: 0.7;
   line-color: #FFF;
   line-width: 1;
   line-opacity: 1;
}

#medicaid_expansion[expansion="Expanding\n"] {
   polygon-fill: #A6CEE3;
}
#medicaid_expansion[expansion="No Expansion"] {
   polygon-fill: #1F78B4;
}
#medicaid_expansion[expansion="Currently in Debate"] {
   polygon-fill: #B2DF8A;
}
#medicaid_expansion[expansion="Expanding"] {
   polygon-fill: #33A02C;
}
#medicaid_expansion[expansion="Expanding\n\n"] {
   polygon-fill: #FB9A99;
}
#medicaid_expansion[expansion="No Expansion\n"] {
   polygon-fill: #E31A1C;
}"
    }

    var sublayer = layer.getSubLayer(0);

    sublayer.set(subLayerOptions);

    sublayers.push(sublayer);
  }).on('error', function() {
    //log the error
  });

  </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
  <div id='cartodb-map'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you js fiddle your code please like http://jsfiddle.net/fillerwriter/9ddLa/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have some syntax errors with your script. For example you are using double quotes for quoting parts of a string when using double quotes for quoting the string itself which will not work.

Also you have linebreaks that are preventing your code from working correctly.

+you have a missing '}' at the end of your script.

Here you have a working version of it. Also remember that SQL and CartoCSS are read-only on private tables.

```
    <html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/themes/css/cartodb.css" />
  <script src="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/cartodb.js"></script>
  <!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v2/themes/css/cartodb.ie.css" />
  <![endif]-->
  <style>
    html, body {width:100%; height:100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
    #cartodb-map { width: 100%; height:100%; background: black;}
  </style>

  <script>
    var map;
    function init(){
      // initiate leaflet map
      map = new L.Map('cartodb-map', { 
        center: [0,0],
        zoom: 2
      })

      var layerUrl = 'http://rjharris.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/8f8fb646-6bbf-11e4-a77f-0e018d66dc29/viz.json';

var sublayers = [];

cartodb.createLayer(map, layerUrl)
  .addTo(map)
  .on('done', function(layer) {
    // change the query for the first layer
    var subLayerOptions = {
      sql: 'SELECT * FROM medicaid_expansion',
      cartocss: '#medicaid_expansion { polygon-opacity: 0.7; line-color: #FFF; line-width: 1; line-opacity: 1;} #medicaid_expansion[expansion="Expanding"] {polygon-fill: #A6CEE3; } #medicaid_expansion[expansion="No Expansion"] { polygon-fill: #1F78B4; } #medicaid_expansion[expansion="Currently in Debate"] { polygon-fill: #B2DF8A;} #medicaid_expansion[expansion="Expanding"] { polygon-fill: #33A02C; } #medicaid_expansion[expansion="Expanding"] { polygon-fill: #FB9A99; }#medicaid_expansion[expansion="No Expansion"] {polygon-fill: #E31A1C;}'
    }

    var sublayer = layer.getSubLayer(0);

    sublayer.set(subLayerOptions);

    sublayers.push(sublayer);
  }).on('error', function() {
    //log the error
  });
}

  </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
  <div id='cartodb-map'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Cheers!